# How do I append a section containing multiple elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have some

```
<section id="something"></section>
```

with a ton of content in between.

And I want to create a click event so when you click "+" it appends that entire section beneath, but gives it the id "something2" so that they can be manipulated separately.

I've uploaded it so it is clear what I am talking about. Navigate to education and look at the section that contains a form for your college info. Clicking the "+" should create another section like that. There won't be an "x" next to the first one as appears currently, but it will be next to each of the added sections.

*EDIT* Forgot the link. http://ravvel.com/markup/createResume.htm

Comment: where have you uploaded and what have you uploaded ?

Comment: I see no `+` on this website.

Comment: Click education. It will take you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("#plus").click(function(){
     var $container = $(this).closest("#container");

     $container.find(".section:first").clone().insertAfter($container.find(".section:last"));
});
```

Be sure to change the selectors to your needs.

Comment: I'm going to give it a shot! I'm a bit confused about the .section:first and .section:last parts.

Comment: `section` should be the class name of the tag that contains all the elements that should be added. (I understand you want to duplicate them so they should exist before). `:first` will select the first instance of it. `:last` will select the last instance of it.

Comment: Will it only work with a class? I used an ID and it isn't working for me, although I may have done something wrong. Wait, let me try again. I think I can see what I did incorrectly.

Comment: Looking at your html, i think using the tag name itself would be best choice: `section:first` and `section:last`, the container could be just `form`. Change the `<div id="append">` to `<div class="append">` and use `.append` as the selector for the button. Be sure to put the script within `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Hmmm, but there are other forms on the page, so I was worried about affecting all of them, you know?

Comment: It cant happen because the way it was written, it will only affect the one that is wrapping around the + button. $(this).closest() will return the closest parent tag that wraps around the clicked element

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. I didn't notice the part where it said to make the section have a class name of section :) thank you!